Python ElementTree – how to edit XML file maintaining certain tags as self-closing?
I am editing an XML file in Python 3.10 using ElementTree.
I need certain empty elements to use self-closing tags, i.e. <a/>, whereas others need to be written out in full <b></b>. It is not clear (to me) what determines whether an empty-element tag is used.
This is because I am editing XML files which are converted to/from bin files by an old game, and the conversion back to bin will fail if the format is not exactly as expected.
The closest answer I've yet found is this post, however I do not know the whole list of tags which need to be self-closing.
Here is how I am loading in the XML file:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filename = 'file.xml'

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

ET.register_namespace("d", r"http://www.kuju.com/TnT/2003/Delta")

I then edit the text attribute of certain elements, before writing a new file:
tree.write('edited.xml', method='html')
or
tree.write('edited.xml', short_empty_elements=False)
Both ways of doing this produce an XML file with the <a></a> format for every element.
How do I preserve the format of empty elements and only edit the value of non-empty elements?

You should expect ET to use a consistent style

short_empty_elements=True

"I do not know the whole list of tags which need to be self-closing." - if requirements are unclear, no code will be able to satisfy them.

XML processing tools might not be able to preserve this kind of syntactic feature, in which case you'll have to fall back on string processing.

Please post code for editable elements detection and a minimal sample of XML document. It might be possible to provide a solution with a mix of text and xml processing.
